# Information stored in session not saving django

Tags: python, django

I've been having trouble with storing my data in django. I'm appending a tuple but everytime I do a post request it shows me an empty array. It should be appending every time? Can anyone give me an idea on why this happens? (my forms and data are working fine the information is received in request.POST)

**views.py**

The session is started when a user logs in

```
    def post(request):
    username = request.POST["username"]
    password = request.POST["password"]

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        request.session['cart'] = []
        return redirect("/")
    else:
        return render(request, 'sign_in.html', {
            "error": "Invalid Credentials"
        })
```

now heres where the problems at

get method (class based view)

```
 def get(request):
    stalls = available_stalls()
    products = Product.objects.all()

    if 'cart' not in request.session:
        request.session['cart'] = []
        cart_count = 0
    else:
        cart_count = len(request.session['cart'])

    context = {
        "stalls": stalls,
        "products": products,
        'cart_count': cart_count
    }

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = request.user
        customer = Customer.objects.filter(user=user)[0]
        full_name = customer.full_name
        context["name"] = full_name

    return render(request, 'product_catalog.html', context)
```

post method (class based view)

```
    def post(request):

    if "product" not in request.POST or "quantity" not in request.POST:
        raise Http404("Product or quantity not in POST data")

    product_id = request.POST["product"]
    quantity = request.POST["quantity"]

    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    except:
        raise Http404("Product ID not in database")


    print(request.session["cart"])
    request.session["cart"].append((product, quantity))
    cart_count = len(request.session['cart'])


    stalls = available_stalls()
    products = Product.objects.all()

    # TODO: Compute recommendations
    return render(request, 'product_catalog.html', {
        'added_to_cart': product,
        'cart_count': cart_count,
        'quantity': quantity,
        'stalls': stalls,
        'products': products
    })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation on [when sessions are saved](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved) explains this. Basically, sessions are only automatically saved when one of the top-level keys is modified. But you are adding an element to an existing list within the session. You will need to explicitly say `request.session.modified = True` to trigger the save.

Comment: Hello! I've tried to add this after the append but it gives me a type error Product object is not JSON serializable

Comment: Again, you should read the docs: the default serializer uses JSON, and model instances are not directly JSON serializable. You could potentially switch to the Pickle serializer, although see the warnings about that in the docs. More usefully, you should also consider why you want to serialize the entire Product instance, rather than just the ID.

Comment: yep I just found my problem I was storing the Product instance. Thanks for your help! this solved my problem

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you, as a sign to future readers.